# Oracle After Insert Trigger - procedure won't run as row doesn't exist yet

Tags: oracle

I have an 'after insert' trigger in Oracle. (let's say table 'tbl_image').

The triggers runs a stored procedure based on the :NEW.ID. The stored proc is meant to generates an image.

However, the image never gets generated. Is this because the row doesn't yet exist in tbl_image? Is there any way around this? I want the stored proc to run based on the new ID/row.

Trigger:

```
create or replace TRIGGER "USER"."TRG_tbl_image" 

AFTER INSERT ON tbl_image 

FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE 

  tmpId INTEGER;

BEGIN
  
  uspCreateImage ('http://imageurl:8080/sm-api', :NEW.Image_ID);
      
END TRG_tbl_image;
```

Comment: Please share your sample code.

Comment: Can you debug code that you cannot see?  No?  Well, neither can anyone else.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I've added my code now

Comment: As if you're trying **so hard** not to get any help. As @EdStevens said, we can't debug code we can't see. Why do you think we know what is uspCreateImage procedure doing? You claim it *generates* an image. How nice of it. Shame it doesn't work.

Comment: "stored proc is meant to generates an image"  And what is this proc - whose code we cannot see - supposed to _do_ with said generated image?  Store it in a table? Write it to a file outside the database? Display it on a screen?  Send it back to the application?

Comment: The SP uspCreateImage makes a call to the back end of our application to generate an image. That image is stored/updated in the same table as my trigger - 'tbl_image'. The SP runs fine by itself. If I run 'uspCreateImage ('http://imageurl:8080/sm-api', 100);' where the image id is 100, it generates fine. My issue is that when the SP is called within this trigger, the image doesn't generate. Maybe there is no solution here, as the new row doesn't yet exist (:new.id).

Comment: It's hard to make any suggestions without knowing how uspCreateImage works. The row does exist because this is an `AFTER` trigger. But I don't think you can modify the table you're inserting into in an after trigger. Is it running with `PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION`?